# Netsuite - How to automate setting Inventory Adjustment worksheet records using a restlet

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to automate doing an Adjust worksheet using a restlet in netsuite with the code below:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define([
    'N/record','N/format',
], function(record,format) {
    function postInv(data){
    var recordObj = record.create({
        type: "inventoryworksheet",
        isDynamic: true
    });

    var location = data.location;
    var account = data.account;
    var region = data.region;
    var countedby = data.countedby;
    var datee = format.parse({value: data.date, type: format.Type.DATE});
    var memo = data.memo;
    var trans_order = data.trans_order;
    var inv_type = data.inv_type;
    var item_group = data.group;

    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'trandate',
        value:datee
    });

    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'location',
        value:location
    });
    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'account',
        value:account
    });
    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'department',
        value:region
    });
    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'lastinday',
        value:trans_order
    });
    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'custbody44',
        value:inv_type
    });

    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'memo',
        value:memo
    });
    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'custbody43',
        value:countedby
    });
    recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'Item_PARENT',
        value:item_group
    });

    var items = data.items;
    var recordsublist = recordObj.getSublist({sublistId: "invt"});
    var linecount = recordObj.getLineCount({sublistId: 'invt'});
    
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        //Search for items line number
        var lineNumber = recordObj.findSublistLineWithValue({
            sublistId: 'invt',
            fieldId: 'invtid',
            value: items[i][0]
            });
                 
        recordObj.selectLine({
            sublistId: 'invt',
            line: lineNumber
            });

            recordObj.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'invt',
            fieldId: 'invtnewqty',
            value: items[i][1]
            });

            recordObj.commitLine({
            sublistId:'invt'
            });
    }
    var recordId = recordObj.save({
        enableSourcing: false,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: false
        });

    var r = record.load({
        type: 'inventorytransfer',
        id: recordId,
        isDynamic: true,
    });
    return r;

    }
    return {post:postInv};
});
```

Since Netsuite hasnt implemented a proper way to Adjust worksheet programmatically, I figured its possible to load the whole Adjust worksheet then loop through all the records and only set the values I want, just like I would in the UI. However this is a bit slow since 10,000 records are loaded by default. I have over 16k items so this also means some wont show in the loaded records.

To make this simpler I tried to only load a single group by specifying the sub-item field using

```
recordObj.setValue({
        fieldId:'Item_PARENT',
        value:item_group
    });
```

However it seems this is just ignored and the whole 10,000 records is still loaded but I think its because the record doesn't change dynamically like in the UI once its been loaded.

Is there a way I can specify the group to load right at the start?

Comment: The Adjust Inventory Worksheet is not something you would normally be doing on a regular basis.  Would usually compare inventory levels (current and what you want it to be) and generate lines for an inventory adjustment to sync with an external system or count.

Comment: @Brian Where I am the adjust worksheet gets done everyday hence the need for automation. I believe its because sometimes transactions are not entered straightaway  so a count could be done today and entered then someone from a separate branch comes in and enters a transaction from 2 days ago. Adjust worksheet is preventing issues with this